# Почему счетчик не правильно считает?

Tags: javascript, jquery, дата, counter

Есть счетчик. За основу взял дату и перевел ее в секунды. Получилось что-то в роде 648767800. По идее настоящее время идет и счетчик не обнуляется и продолжает считать, вроде все хорошо. Но изначально у меня было так

`function time(){
          return parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);
    }`

и считало аж с 1970 года (сколько секунд прошло с того момента). Но потом переделал под нужную дату так

`function time() { 
          start = new Date("July 24, 1990");
          return parseInt(start.getTime()/1000);
    }`

и счетчик всегда начинал считать с 648767800. Т.е. счет не сохранялся при перезагрузке. Как сделать чтобы он продолжал считать, а именно учитывать сколько секунд прошло с той даты?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверно как-то так:

```
function time() {
  now = parseInt(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  start = parseInt(new Date("July 24, 1990").getTime() / 1000);

  return now - start;
}
```